# Exit Python Tkinter app cleanly while also using "wait_variable" function on a button in an "after" loop

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, tk-toolkit

I have a problem similar to this post: [Exit program within a tkinter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988801/exit-program-within-a-tkinter-class)

My variation on the problem involves the `wait_variable` being used on a button to control "stepping forward" in an app, **but also allowing the app to close cleanly**.

See my code below:

```
# To see output unbuffered:
#   python -u delete_win_test.py

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Close the app when the window's X is pressed
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.closing)

        # When this var is set to 1, the move function can continue
        self.var = tk.IntVar()

        # Close the app if the button is pressed
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                           command=self.destroy)
        button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

        # Step forward
        self.step_button = tk.Button(self, text="Step",
                                     command=lambda: self.var.set(1))
        self.step_button.place(relx=.5, rely=.75, anchor="c")

    def move(self):
        print("doing stuff")  # simulates stuff being done
        self.step_button.wait_variable(self.var)
        self.after(0, self.move)

    def closing(self):
        self.destroy()


app = GUI()
app.move()
app.mainloop()
```

- The window shows correctly
- "Stepping forward" works because "doing stuff" prints to terminal on button click
- Exiting the window by both pressing X or using the "exit" button both work

**The problem:** the Python app never exits from the terminal and requires a closing of the terminal.

How can I make the Python program exit cleanly so the user does not need to close and re-open a new terminal window?

Related references for animation, etc:

- Animation using self.after: [moving circle using tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849592/moving-circle-using-tkinter)
- Button wait: [Making Tkinter wait untill button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790449/making-tkinter-wait-untill-button-is-pressed)
- The original "exit" code: [Exit program within a tkinter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61988801/exit-program-within-a-tkinter-class)

**UPDATE (the solution):**

(Credit to both response answers below)

```
         # Close the app if the button is pressed
         button = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
-                           command=self.destroy)
+                           command=self.closing)
         button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")
 
         # Step forward
...
     def closing(self):
         self.destroy()
+        self.var.set("")
+        exit(0)
```

This allows the native window's "X" to close the window **and** the Tk button to close the window **while still closing the Python app cleanly in the terminal**.

Comment: Why dont you set `self.var` to a special int in your `closing` method and dont continue with `move` if this special int is set? Working with a `if statement` solves this anyhow and shouldnt be too hard to solve for you.

Comment: Hi @Atlas435, I see what you mean with `self.var`, however can you explain what you mean by the `if statement`?  Is that a separate solution or related to `self.var`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `closing` function needs to set the variable to cause the app to stop waiting.

```
def closing(self):
    self.destroy()
    self.var.set("")
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, thank you for the response, but this did not work for me.  The Python app still does not exit cleanly in the terminal even though the window closes (using X or the close button).  Tested on both Windows Git Bash and Mac OSX.

Comment: @masao: that's odd. It works for me on OSX.

Comment: Hi again Bryan, here's my environment:
`tk==0.1.0`
`toml==0.10.2`

Python version: `Python 3.9.4`

Does this match your environment?

Comment: Solution posted in original post!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

in the closing function, you need to call exit to exit the program.

```py
def closing(self):
    self.destroy() #closes tkinkter window
    exit(0) #exits program
```

Comment: Thanks!  I combined this with other answers and found the solution (see original post)!